# Find and replace variable div contents

Tags: dom, html, replace

I have a php page which contains a large amount of HTML in it. One part of the HTML has a div in the following format:

```
<div class="reusable-block" id="xyzabcwy">there is a lot of HTML here which may be in any format</div>
```

Keep in mind, this div is contained within the DOM at any location however, I do know the div ID programatically.

I was originally finding this string within my database, since a record of it exists there however, the format between the data in the database record and the page are sometimes different due to whitespace but other than the white space, the strings are exactly the same. The problem is, I don't know what format the whitespace is in.

It seems it is better to write a regular expression to find this div and replace it entirely.
I could use a hand though.

Other ideas are also welcome.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery,

```
$('#xyzabcwy').html(new_data);
```

if not

```
document.getElementById('xyzabcwy').innerHTML = new_data;
```

otherwise, here is a PHP example.

Edit: PHP

```
<?php
 $id = "xyzabcwy";
 $html = "<div id=\"" . $id . "\">this is html</div>";
 $newdata = "test";
 echo preg_replace("#<div[^>]*id=\"{$id}\".*?</div>#si",$newdata,$html);
?>
```

This should output

```
<div id="123">test</div>
```

Answer from: [Replace a div content with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476045/replace-a-div-content-with-php)